# Why can't I concatenate this list in order to switch characters?

Tags: python

I'm having this problem and have been up for hours trying to work it out, does anyone know what might be going wrong?

When I write

```
plant = 'blackberry'
temp = list(plant)

    def switch(xs):
        return [xs[1]] + xs[0] + [xs[2:-1]]
```

and then call it in

```
switch(temp)
```

I get the error 'TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list'

I'm wondering why? I'm trying to do a switch of the first two letters of blackberry where the input isn't modified to memory, so that if I was to call

```
temp
```

afterwards, then it would still be 'blackberry' rather than the switched version - does anyone know how to get rid of this error?

I'd be very grateful for any clarification on this

Comment: `[xs[1]]` is `list` with one element - `str`, `xs[0]` is `str` and `[xs[2:-1]]` is `list` with one element, again `list`. And as the error states, _can only concatenate list (not "str") to list'_

Comment: `return [xs[1] + xs[0] + ''.join(xs[2:])]`

Answer (score 0):

Look at what each item you are returning actually is:

```
print([xs[1]]) # ['l']
print(xs[0]) # 'b'
print([xs[2:-1]]) # [['a', 'c', 'k', 'b', 'e', 'r', 'r']]

return [xs[1]] + xs[0] + [xs[2:-1]]
# ['l'] + 'b' + [['a', 'c', 'k', 'b', 'e', 'r', 'r']]
```

You cannot add different elements like this. You need to make sure they are all the same type, i.e.:

```
return [xs[1]] + [xs[0]] + xs[2:-1]
# ['l'] + ['b'] + ['a', 'c', 'k', 'b', 'e', 'r', 'r']
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I think I'm almost there after making the changes, however the output is returning with the brackets, do you know why that might be? Sort of like this: ['l', 'b', ['a', 'c', 'k', 'b', 'e', 'r', 'r', 'y']]

Comment: Did you copy exactly what I had in my last line? It returns as a single list without the inner brackets...

Comment: Got it, thank you so much kind sir, you have bestowed upon me a great gift of knowledge this day

Answer (score 0):

`xs[1]` is `"l"`

`[xs[1]]` is `["l"]`

`xs[0]` is `"b"`

`xs[2:-1]` is `['a', 'c', 'k', 'b', 'e', 'r', 'r']`

`[xs[2:-1]]` is `[['a', 'c', 'k', 'b', 'e', 'r', 'r']]`

As you can see:

`[xs[2:-1]]` is a list

`[xs[1]]` is a list

`xs[0]` is a string

In python, string and list cannot be concatenated. That means, one cannot add a string with a list.

In general you can use `type()` function to see the type of a variable. For example:

`print(type(xs[0]))` results in this output: `<class 'list'>`

Comment: `[xs[2:-1]]` is a list of lists

Comment: A list of list is still a list

Comment: Sure, but I thought it would help to highlight the difference, since there is a difference

Answer (score 0):

The xs[2:-1] is an array whereas xs[1], xs[0] are just characters which work as strings so there is conflict in concatenation

Further list concatenation to strings is done via join methods

```
String = "<anyString>".join(listarr)
```

The following solution will work for your case

```
plant = 'blackberry'
temp = list(plant)

def switch(xs):
    print("".join([xs[1], xs[0], "".join(xs[2:])]))
    return "".join([xs[1], xs[0], "".join(xs[2:])])

switch(temp)
```