# Defining a function for concatenation which works for strings and lists. How?

Tags: python, list

I’m confused about why this can work for strings but not for lists. Does anyone have any suggestions as to why it might be?

```
def switcheroo(test):
    
    return test[1] + test[0] + test[2:]
```

Comment: If `test` is a `list` then `test[1]` and `test[0]` are just elements (such as `int`) they are not themselves lists. Conversely if `test` is a `str` even indexing a single character still returns another `str` which you can then concatenate.

Comment: If you take slices from a list you will get lists and can add them together, and it would work for strings too: `test[1:2] + test[0:1] + test[2:]`

Answer (score 1):

Although string and lists are both sequences, the interpretation of `[]` brackets varies depending on what expression is inside of them. If it's just a single integer value, then it used a the index of that element in the string or list, but when it the expression contains one or more `:` characters it's a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice) and it evaluates to the specified subset of the original object — i.e. a substring or a sublist.

A way to write a function that handles both would be to restrict yourself to using slices:

```
def switcheroo(test):
#    return test[1] + test[0] + test[2:]
    return test[1:2] + test[0:1] + test[2:]


test1 = 'abcdef'
print(switcheroo(test1))  # -> bacdef

test2 = ['st','ack','over','flow']
print(switcheroo(test2))  # -> ['ack', 'st', 'over', 'flow']
```

Answer (score 0):

When `test` is a `str` any of the three - `test[1]` ,  `test[0]`, and `test[2:]` are `str`. When `test` is a `list`, first two -`test[1]` and  `test[0]` are `str`, but `test[2:]` is a `list` (even with one element). And as discussed in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69717671/4046632), you cannot concatenate `str` and `list`.

Note, I say `str`, but they can be any type. I just know they are `str` from your other question.